# Semi Circular Slider

Tags: ios, uislider

I need to implement a semi circular UISlider control . I googled a lot but could not find any solution . Even i tried to transform the UISlider but could not get success. Please help me .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Mihir,
Were you able to find a solution to this? I need to create something like this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have googled wrong :) http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/uicircularslider. You can see what he is doing to create circular slider, and create your own semi-circular slider. Good Luck!

Comment: i got that but that does not satisfy my requirement as i need to add image in the slider.In that control there are colors to fill active and inactive portion of slider.I tried colorwithpattern but could not get success..

Comment: Dear, some thing are there to figure out by yourself. Your task is not that difficult to accomplish. Here, we can advise you how to achieve your goal, but we can't do all the work for you :). Consider this example project as starting point.